# What kinds of documents were forged in the middle ages and how common was forgery?

Tags: middle-ages, forgery

For example I was reading about the [Privilegium Maius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilegium_Maius), and was wondering what other instances of document forging were there in the middle ages ?

Comment: [Hoaxes of the Middle Ages](http://hoaxes.org/archive/display/category/middleages/) is a category on Hoaxes.org.  Also look for forged genealogies!

Comment: Not sur if you'd count that as a forgery, but someone wealthy enough could make himself pass as a noble by behaving and dressing like one.

Comment: @MakorDal: That's a bit dodgy - you wold have to bribe a School of Heraldry in order to obtain a sigil, and even then there was no great likelihood of non discovery.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I agree. But people would seldom ask to see those things. It was firstly in the behaviour and a few generations down the road, someone would give your family a title anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Forgery was common in medieval time, beginning with the most famous one:
[the Donation of Constantine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donation_of_Constantine).

Very common objects of forgery were holy relics which were traded in great quantities. Europe was full of the itinerant merchant selling these [relics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relic).

Answer (score -1):

[The Pseudo-Isidore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Isidorian_Decretals) is a case in point. Peter Heather has a very interesting account of it, in [one of his books](https://books.google.co.il/books/about/The_Restoration_of_Rome.html?id=g8tbAwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y).